# How to update multiple rows from values of first row in same table in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in the low code application Quickbase. Once I import data from the spreadsheet which populates the Customer Name, Invoice Num, Invoice Date and Invoice Amount columns. Then, I manually data enter the client ID & Customer ID in only the first row. I am planning to add a psql query in a separate table which interacts with Postgres database of the application. This trigger should update the other rows with the values of Client ID & Customer ID from first row. I am not sure how to move forward with this. If a Join statement is required?

Comment: Sounds like a weird design. You should overthink that.

Comment: The rows to be updated must have some unique combination of values (e.g., from columns customer name, invoice number, invoice date, and invoice amount) in common with the row for which you manually entered the data.  Then you can use these to join a subquery containing the completed client ID with the matching rows that have no client ID.  Post some example data if you need more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Update table set clientid=(select top clientid from table where clientid is not null)

Update table set clientname=(select top clientname from table where clientname is not null)